# How to set an entry value to Zero if entry is blank in python tkinter?

Tags: python, tkinter, error-handling, tkinter-entry

The following code works nomally if we pass a value in entry but the problem is with the blank entry it shows
              _tkinter.TclError: expected floating-point number but got ""

```
from tkinter import *

root_tk = Tk()
def calculater():
    entry_list = [Entryvalue,...,..,sometingelsevalues,]
    for entryd in entry_list:
        if entryd==None:
            entryd.set(0)
value1=Entryvalue.get()*20
print(value1)
Entryvalue=IntVar()
Entry = Entry(root_tk,textvariable=Entryvalue).grid(row=0, column=2, padx="25")
Buttoncalculate = Button(root_tk, text="Calculate", fg="blue", command=calculater).grid(row=7, column=0)
```

I tried several methods which is in following codes but problem not resolved

```
1.
def calculater():
    entry_list = [Entryvalue,...,..,sometingelsevalues,]
    for entryd in entry_list:
        if len(entryd.get())==0:
            entryd.set(0)
value1=Entryvalue.get()*20
print(value1)
```

```
2.def calculater():
    entry_list = [Entryvalue,...,..,sometingelsevalues,]
    for entryd in entry_list:
        if entryd=="":
            entryd.set(0)
value1=Entryvalue.get()*20
print(value1)
```

it converts all inputs in 0

```
3.def calculater():
    entry_list = [Entryvalue,...,..,sometingelsevalues,]
    for entryd in entry_list:
        if not entryd==None:
            entryd.set(0)
value1=Entryvalue.get()*20
print(value1)
```

Comment: Try binding `<FocusOut>` event to a callback, then in the callback check whether input is empty, if yes set the content to "0".  But better initialise the entry to "0" as well.

Answer (score 1):

```
from tkinter import *

entry = Entry()
entry.pack()


def zero(evt):
    if entry.get() == '':
        entry.insert(END, '0')
entry.bind('<KeyRelease>', zero)
```

Hope that's helpful!

Answer (score 0):

finally I achieved

```
def anyfun()
  if Entry.get()==''
   Entry.insert(0,END)

#now you can do anything in function
```

now you will not get the error
TclError: expected floating-point number but got ""

Answer (score 0):

you can try this method:

```
from tkinter import*
root=Tk()
etvb=StringVar()
et1=StringVar()
et2=StringVar()
def plus():
    if e1.get()=="":
        e1.insert(END,"0")
    if e2.get()=="":
        e2.insert(END,"0")
    etvb.set(int(e1.get())+int(e2.get()))
    if e1.get()=="0":
        et1.set("")
    if e2.get()=="0":
        et2.set("")
e1=Entry(root,width=6,textvariable=et1)
e1.place(x=30,y=30)
e2=Entry(root,width=6,textvariable=et2)
e2.place(x=30,y=60)
e3=Entry(root,width=6,textvariable=etvb)
e3.place(x=30,y=90)
etvb.set("")

L1=Label(root,text="No. 1")
L1.place(x=80,y=30)
L2=Label(root,text="No. 2")
L2.place(x=80,y=60)
L3=Label(root,text="Plus")
L3.place(x=80,y=90)
b=Button(root,width=8,text="plus",command=plus)
b.place(x=30,y=130)

root.mainloop()
```